# How do I set the baseUrl in Playwright without using the global config

Tags: javascript, testing, playwright

I'm using Playwright to do some task automation. I don't want to use global config (`playwright.config.ts`). However, I'd still like to use a common `baseUrl` for all of my tasks. How do I set the `baseUrl` if I don't have a global config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can set the `baseUrl` when creating a context:

```js
const browser = await chromium.launch({
  headless: true,
});

const context = await browser.newContext({
  baseURL: "https://example.com",
});
```

You'll have to do this individually for every context you create (unlike the `baseUrl` in the global config). But it works.